# Devise: Current_user will throw nil even after using before_action :authenticate_api_v1_user! in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

For a particular API call, and while debugging directly in the Api Controller, when trying to access the current user, it is taken as nil, even when `before_action :authenticate_api_v1_user!` is set in the controller.

A weird thing is than, when I try to access `current_user`, the log still shows a Postgres SQL query that, when I run it in an SQL client, returns the user I need. But this user won't be set in the variable:

```
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["uid", "email@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb:28:in `current_user'
nil
```

This does not happen to other API calls in other controllers, since I can access `current_user` without any problem in them. In these, when accessing `current_user` the debug output shows that it's being set:

```
User Load (137.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["uid", "email@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb:28:in `current_user'
#<User id: 29, provider: "email", uid: "email@email.com", allow_password_change: false, name: nil, nickname: nil, image: nil, email: "email@email.com", created_at: "2019-12-16 14:58:31", updated_at: "2022-05-19 18:22:05", parent_id: nil, role: "admin", first_name: "Fito", last_name: "Hoyos", company: nil>
```

For all tests, I'm using the same 3 headers:

- uid
- access-token
- client

Comment: would be useful to see the place code is actually failing.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was of **concept about class and instance methods**. In order to have more code readability, I had refactored into multiple methods and files, and some of those methods were class methods that did not have access to the current_user variable.